# How to save an imagelist as one bitmap like a tilesheet?

Tags: delphi

I have an image list containing several bitmaps which I would like to save together as one single bitmap, but I need it saving just like how a spritesheet or tilesheet is drawn in 2d and rpg games etc.

Typically the tilesheet is drawn with several images across (in a row), so for example if I wanted a maximum of 6 images per row, it will only draw 6, with further images been drawn underneath in a new row.

I can save it in one single row like so:

```
var
  CurrentFrame: Integer;
  StripWidth: Integer;

  Strip: TBitmap;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if SaveDialog.Execute then
  begin
    StripWidth   := ImageList1.Width * ImageList1.Count - ImageList1.Width;
    CurrentFrame := - ImageList1.Width;

    Strip := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Strip.SetSize(StripWidth, ImageList1.Height);
      Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        for I := 0 to ImageList1.Count - 1 do
        begin
          CurrentFrame := CurrentFrame + ImageList1.Width;
          ImageList1.GetImage(I, Bmp);
          Strip.Canvas.Draw(CurrentFrame, 0, Bmp);
        end;
      finally
        Bmp.Free;
      end;

      Strip.SaveToFile(SaveDialog.FileName);
    finally
      Strip.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So imagine the result for the above is:

[image]

The result I want is something like:

[image]

So the above would have considered in the procedure/ function a parameter to allow only 3 images per row as an example.

How do I export all images from an imagelist into one single bitmap, allowing only x amount if images to be drawn horizontally before creating a new row?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to David's answer, I put together these procedures:

```
procedure DrawImageOnSheet(Images: TImageList; Sheet: TBitmap;
  ImageIndex, X, Y: Integer);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Images.GetBitmap(ImageIndex, Bitmap);
    Sheet.Canvas.Draw(X, Y, Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure SaveImageListAsSheet(Images: TImageList; FileName: string;
  NumberOfColumns: Integer);
var
  Sheet: TBitmap;

  nImage: Integer;
  nCol: Integer;
  nRow: Integer;
  nToDraw: Integer;
  nRemaining: Integer;

  ImageIndex: Integer;

  X, Y: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Sheet := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    nImage := Images.Count;
    nCol   := NumberOfColumns;
    nRow   := (nImage + nCol - 1) div nCol;

    Sheet.Height := nRow * Images.Height;
    Sheet.Width  := nCol * Images.Width;

    nRemaining := nImage;
    ImageIndex := 0;
    Y := 0;
    while nRemaining > 0 do
    begin
      nToDraw := Math.Min(nRemaining, nCol);
      X := 0;
      for I := 0 to nToDraw - 1 do
      begin
        DrawImageOnSheet(Images, Sheet, ImageIndex, X, Y);
        Inc(ImageIndex);
        Inc(X, Images.Width);
      end;
      Inc(Y, Images.Height);
      Dec(nRemaining, nToDraw);
    end;

    Sheet.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Sheet.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use simple mathmatics to calculate the row

Comment: Well, paint it yourself the way you need. If you have the top image the bottom one is simple to draw.

Comment: @SirRufo its not so simple to me :(

Comment: @DavidHeffernan like Sir Rufo said I need to calculate it and because the imagelist could contain anything its confused me. I know I should calculate the bitmap height and width first, then draw each rows into it but its the maths part that I struggle with.

Comment: First of all you need to decide how many rows/cols. Do want it close to square? Or always 3 cols? Or what?

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear when I said "the above would have considered in the procedure/ function a parameter", the parameter been how many columns there should be (again sorry I got columns and rows mixed up before). If there was a parameter to pass an Integer value of how many columns that would be better, so you could pass 4, 5, 6 columns etc or whatever. To be honest the code I posted for a regular strip is bad anyway I imagine. Thanks, and sorry for not been so clear.

Comment: Draw the first row of ncol items. Then the next row. Stop when there's nothing more to draw. Are you stuck on the counting or the drawing?

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you skipped I=0?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that was a mistake I must of accidentally included when I pasted the code (I was messing around trying different things) - it should be `I := 0 to`. The drawing part I guess should be easy`ish`, but only once the `counting` or calculating` part is right, thats what I am confused about, especially when the imagelist is not a fixed size or amount of images. I tried using variables and `Inc` but I kept getting lost off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to clarification from the comments, you are struggling with the counting of the images, the organisation of the rows/columns and so on. So, let's assume you already have this function which draws image `ImageIndex` to the output bitmap at a position of `X`, `Y`.

```
procedure Draw(ImageIndex, X, Y: Integer);
```

Let's also assume that the images have dimensions given by `ImageWidth` and `ImageHeight`. Finally, there are `nImage` images and you want to have `nCol` images per column.

So, first of all, how many rows do you need?

```
nRow := (nImage + nCol - 1) div nCol;
```

Now you can set the size of the output bitmap. Its width is `nCol * ImageWidth` and its height is `nRow * ImageHeight`.

Now to draw the images.

```
nRemaining := nImage;
ImageIndex := 0;
Y := 0;
while nRemaining > 0 do
begin
  nToDraw := Math.Min(nRemaining, nCol);
  X := 0;
  for i := 0 to nToDraw - 1 do
  begin
    Draw(ImageIndex, X, Y);
    inc(ImageIndex);
    inc(X, ImageWidth);
  end;
  inc(Y, ImageHeight);
  dec(nRemaining, nToDraw);
end;
```

Comment: See, I knew it! straight away you have code in there I would not think of trying or knowing when/how to use, such as `Math.Min`! Its getting a bit late so I will take a proper look tomorrow but thanks for the explanation with your answer.

Comment: This works well thanks very much, I really do appreciate writing the answer and explaining it because although to many such as yourself and Sir Rufo who think this is simple maths, to someone like me I find these type of calculations quite confusing (and the more time I spend looking at code the more confusing it can become!). Now I will read the documentation on those keywords such as `Math.Min` to try and get a better understanding of it all. My initial approach was using `I` and `J` loops with `Inc` and all kinds of mess! Thanks again David.

Comment: I think I may have been a little hasty accepting the answer without further testing. It worked on some imagelists, but others are not and I suspect it is because I have not implemented `nRow` into it. I have edited my question to show code based off your answer, perhaps you could point me in the right direction what I need to change? With the code updated in the original question it sometimes missed images off the final saved bitmap which I assume I have missed some important part out of the code? Thanks

Comment: `Sheet.Height := nCol * Images.Height;` is wrong. What if you need more rows than cols? You need to do it exactly as written in the answer.

Comment: Yeah i saw that is wrong, thats when I realised I am completely missing `nRow`.

Comment: Ok, I got it now - sorry for not understanding. It took me a few times to read to understand it all, check my edit on the question does it look right now? From my quick tests it seems to work ok.

Comment: Yup, that looks fine, but I didn't check too closely to be honest

Comment: Seems to be working ok now thanks. It is actually quite interesting the code, paticularly how you used the `dec(nRemaining, nToDraw);`. I actually set a breakpoint on `nToDraw := Math.Min(nRemaining, nCol);` and it was interesting looking at the variables change when stepping through, this actually helped me get a bit of a better insight as to what was happening :)